# Maxwell's Equations In Curved Spacetime Derived Via ADM Formalism VS Differential Forms Discrepancy

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, differential-geometry, adm-formalism

I' m trying to understand how the electromagnetic potential for diagonal Bianchi IX models when an electromagnetic field is aligned with one of the three axis is computed. The metric in question is

\begin{equation}d s^{2}=-d t^{2}+g_{i j}(t) \omega^{i} \omega^{j}\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\omega^{0} &=dt \\
\omega^{1} &=\cos \psi d \theta+\sin \psi \sin \theta d \varphi \\
\omega^{2} &=\sin \psi d \theta-\cos \psi \sin \theta d \varphi \\
\omega^{3} &=d \psi+\cos \theta d \varphi
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
and

\begin{equation}g_{ij}=\operatorname{diag}\left(e^{2\alpha(t)+2 \beta(t)_{+}+2 \sqrt{3} \beta(t)_{-}}, e^{2\alpha(t)+2 \beta(t)_{+}-2 \sqrt{3} \beta(t)_{-}}, e^{2\alpha(t)+-4 \beta(t)_{+}}\right).\end{equation}

In one of the paper I'm reading they derive Maxwell's equations using the ADM formalism  where they use this Lagrangian

\begin{aligned}
\mathscr{L}=& \Pi^{i j} \dot{g}_{i j}+\frac{N \sqrt{g}}{g}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\Pi_{k}^{k}\right)^{2}-\Pi^{i j} \Pi_{i j}\right]+2 \Pi_{i j}^{i j} N_{i}+N \sqrt{g} R \\
&+16 \pi \Pi^{s} \dot{A}_{s}-32 \pi^{2} \frac{N \sqrt{g}}{g} \Pi^{s} \Pi^{p} g_{p s}-N \sqrt{g} g^{i k} g^{r l} \epsilon_{m i r} \epsilon_{n k l} A_{m} A_{n}-16 \pi N_{i} g^{i k} \epsilon_{m k j} \Pi^{j} A_{m}
\end{aligned}

and vary it with respect to $\Pi^{s}$ and $A_{s}$. The resulting equations are

\begin{equation}\dot{A}_{s}-4 \pi \frac{N \sqrt{g}}{g}  \Pi_{s}=0\end{equation}
and

\begin{equation}\dot{\Pi}^{s}+\frac{1}{4 \pi} \frac{N \sqrt{g}}{g} g_{m s} A_{m}=0\end{equation} where $\Pi^{s}$ is the electric field and $A_{s}$ is the magnetic field. I'm assuming the only non zero component of the electromagnet field is the $E_{3}$ and $B_{3}$ component for now, but eventually want to also do the cases when the only non zero components are  $E_{2}$ and $B_{2}$, and  $E_{1}$ and $B_{1}$.

I have no problem deriving these equations and am very familiar with the ADM formalism. However when I begin to derive these same equations using differential forms I don't see how I will get the same equations.

Starting with the vector potential 1 form $\boldsymbol{A}=A_{0}dt+A_{1}\omega^{1}+A_{2}\omega^{2}+A_{3}\omega^{3}$ I compute $d\boldsymbol{A}$ and exploit the Lie algebra of the one forms

\begin{equation}d \omega^{i}=\frac{1}{2} C_{j k}^{i} \omega^{j} \wedge \omega^{k}\end{equation} where the structure constants are \begin{equation}C_{j k}^{i}=\epsilon_{i j k}\end{equation} to obtain $d\boldsymbol{A}=\partial_{u}A_{v}\omega^{u}\omega^{v}+\frac{1}{2}A_{a}\epsilon_{aij}\omega^{i}\omega^{j}$ where Greek indices go from 0 to 3 and Latin from 1 to 3. Moving forward taking $d^{2}\boldsymbol{A}=0$ and its Hodge dual analogue I don't see how I can obtain the same Maxwell's equation that were derived via the ADM Lagrangian. I don't see where $4\pi$ would come from.

Is there something I am missing? I don't expect anyone to actually workout the expression using the differential forms, but if someone does that would be massively appreciated. If not any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: This will be my one and only time bumping this question.

Comment: This will be my last comment.